# Translating Polish certificate

Tags: marriage-records, poland

I have this certificate and I need to translate the 4th row which is for Epstein Isaak.

[image: enter image description here][1]]

How can I get started?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a native Polish speaker. 4th row reads, with headers:

**Liczba bieżąca** record number

**Ulica (Plac) i Nr. domu orjentacyjny i konskrypcyjny** Street (square) and house number - literally "approximate and for conscription"

**Lp. 2135**

**Nr. dom** (empty)

**Imię i nazwisko, zawód główny i stanowisko w nim** Name and surname, main occupation and position in it

**Epstein Izaak szewc** shoemaker

**Stan cywilny oraz pokrewieństwo z głową rodziny** Marital status and relationship to the head of the family

**żonaty** married

**Wyznanie religijne** religious denomination

**"** (means "as above", so "mojżesz." - Jewish)

**Urodzenie / Dzień, miesiac, rok (ew. lata) / Miejsce urodzin / Powiat / Państwo** Birth / Day, month, year (or years) / Place of birth / Powiat (roughly equal to county) / Country

**1885 / Jasień / Brzesko / Polska**

**od kiedy przebywa a) w Krakowie b) stale c) chwilowo** since when is staying in a) Kraków b) permanently c) temporarily

**a) 1917 b) stale c) -** (permanently, since 1917)

**Obecne obywatelstwo państwowe** Current state citizenship

**polskie b.d.** Polish (b.d. usually means "brak danych" - no (more) data)

**Język ojczysty** Native language

**polski żargon** Polish jargon (possibly, but not certainly, referring to yiddish)

**Narodowość** Nationality

**polska** Polish (this was possibly self-declared, as some other Polish citizens on this page have **żydowska** - Jewish - in this column)

Answer (score 2):

When you are translating records, it is important to know where a record came from, the date it was created in relation to the event, and what type of record it is. Since we don't have that information, I will give a general answer.

Start with the FamilySearch Wiki article [Polish Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Poland_Genealogy).

Under the heading **Research Tools**, look for the [Polish Genealogical Word List](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Polish_Genealogical_Word_List) and other tools.

In the box at the right-hand side of the page, under Record Types, look for the article on [Poland Civil Registration](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Poland_Civil_Registration) or whatever record type you have. These articles usually give a sample record and list what kind of information you might be able to find in them.

Read the main article on Polish Genealogy thoroughly.  As you scroll down the page, you will see links to many research aids such as lessons on how to read  the handwriting (palaeography), a [Polish Civil Registration Reading Aid](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Polish_Civil_Registration_Reading_Aid), a link to the [FB Poland Genealogy Group](https://sites.google.com/view/polishgenealogygroup/home?authuser=0) website which has [translation tools](https://sites.google.com/view/polishgenealogygroup/internet-tools/translation-tools?authuser=0), and more.